# How to make a button work as a link in erb?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

```
<%= link_to 'New Post', new_post_path %>
```

This produces link to `new_post_path`. Previously i used `<input type="submit" class="new" name="Addlist" value="Add New" />` which resembled like a button. So how can i make the link look like button in erb?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Just to throw another option out there since I had a scenario where the button_to option didn't work. This looks kind of similar to that.

```
<%= link_to '<button type="button">New Post</button>'.html_safe, new_post_path %>
```

What I basically wanted is a button that doesn't turn into a submit, since I have multiple buttons on the page that aren't related to a form, and I really just want it to just go to another page.

Comment: It could be dangerous in some rails versions. It is more apropriate stylize the link to looks like a button. See [Rails XSS](https://github.com/rails/rails_xss)

Comment: When you validate this markup using http://validator.w3.org/ you will get an error: **The element button must not appear as a descendant of the a element.** not allowed to put a button inside a link...!  Try it yourself: copy the text from: https://gist.github.com/nelsonic/7986797 and paste it into the validator.

Answer (score 10):

Take a look at [**button_to**](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-button_to). In summary it will be simmilar to this:

```
<%= button_to "New Post", { :action => "new" }, :method => :get %>
```

Although be aware, this method accepts the `:method` and `:confirm` modifiers described in the `link_to` documentation. If no `:method` modifier is given, it will default to performing a `POST` operation. You can also disable the button by passing `:disabled => true` in `html_options`. If you are using RESTful routes, you can pass the `:method` to change the HTTP verb used to submit the form.

Answer (score 8):

@Ryan's answer is good but sadly *fails* html validation http://validator.w3.org/

**error: The element button must not appear as a descendant of the a element.**

Why not simply apply a (CSS) ***class*** to your link and make it *appear* as a button.

erb:

`<%= link_to "Button Text", new_post_path, class: 'button' %>`

produces (*valid* & *semantic*) HTML:

`<a class="button" href="/post/new">Button Text</a>`

which you can then *style* to **look** like a button.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/nelsonic/FQK9M/7/